# Re adjustment of path in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, path

Is there anyway to re adjust the path? I tried & tried but completely failed

[image: How to make this path perfect]

Comment: Could you please be a little clearer? How do you want to readjust this path, what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the **Direct Selection Tool** (the white arrow) to click the anchors and adjust them.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of that path, you may be looking to do a <kbd>Object > Path -> Simplify</kbd> on it.